# NoClassDefFound after Gradle and Android Studio upgrade

Tags: android, android-studio, noclassdeffounderror, build.gradle, android-multidex

Since I upgraded Android Studio, I was kinda forced to moving on Gradle's version, buildToolsVersion, and java's version to 7.

And my problem is that I can actually run the project on Android Lollipop perfectly, but I lost compatibility backwards, I'm not able to run application on devices prior API 21.

**Android Studio version:** 1.0.2
**Gradle Wrapper Version:** gradle-2.2.1-all

I followed every step of [Configuring Your App for Multidex with Gradle](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) guide.

**TL;DR** code compiles perfectly, runs on Android Lollipop, doesn't run prior lollipop.

```java
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.mundodescuento'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            proguardFile('proguard-rules.pro')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.MundoDescuento
            debuggable false
            jniDebuggable false
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }

        debug {
            proguardFile('proguard-rules.pro')
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable true
            renderscriptDebuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            zipAlignEnabled false
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```

As Dependency also declared

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Project's root dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'
}
```

My application class extends MultiDexApplication as requested.

```
public class MundoDescuentoApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
    ...
}
```

The Stack Trace I'm getting when running the project on a Android 4.0.3 device:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:957)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:942)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:477)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3938)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1185)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mundodescuento/model/request_params/LoginForm
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:703)
            at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:662)
            at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:356)
            at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:151)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies(InjectorImpl.java:585)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup(InjectorImpl.java:543)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:529)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:847)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:772)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:256)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:205)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalFactory(InjectorImpl.java:853)
            at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.notify(FactoryProxy.java:46)
            at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.runCreationListeners(ProcessedBindingData.java:50)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:133)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
            at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
            at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
            at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
            at com.mundodescuento.MundoDescuentoApplication.<clinit>(MundoDescuentoApplication.java:22)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:957)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:942)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:477)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3938)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1185)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mundodescuento.model.request_params.LoginForm
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:703)
            at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:662)
            at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:356)
            at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:151)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies(InjectorImpl.java:585)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup(InjectorImpl.java:543)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:529)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:847)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:772)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:256)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:205)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalFactory(InjectorImpl.java:853)
            at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.notify(FactoryProxy.java:46)
            at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.runCreationListeners(ProcessedBindingData.java:50)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:133)
            at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
            at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)
            at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)
            at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)
            at com.mundodescuento.MundoDescuentoApplication.<clinit>(MundoDescuentoApplication.java:22)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:957)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:942)
            at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:477)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3938)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1185)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT 02/10/15: Added MundoDescuentoApplication.java and LoginForm.java**

The line from the class which appears in the stacktrace is `private static final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ApplicationGuiceModule(), new GsonModule());`

```
package com.mundodescuento;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;

import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.mundodescuento.module.ApplicationGuiceModule;
import com.mundodescuento.module.GsonModule;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils;

/**
 * Created by gmuniz on 6/30/14.
 */
public class MundoDescuentoApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

    private static MundoDescuentoApplication mInstance;
    private static final String SHARED_PREFFERENCES = "com.mundodescuento.Prefferences";
    private static final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ApplicationGuiceModule(), new GsonModule());

    private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;

        Parse.initialize( ... );
        ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(getString(R.string.facebook_app_id));

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves an instance from the {@link SharedPreferences}
     *
     * @return
     */
    public static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences() {
        return MundoDescuentoApplication.sharedPreferences;
    }

    /**
     * This is a convenience for {@link com.google.inject.Injector#injectMembers(Object) Injector.injectMembers(Object object)}
     */
    public static void injectMembers(final Object object) {
        injector.injectMembers(object);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the application in a static way.
     *
     * @return the context.
     */
    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return mInstance;
    }
}
```

The LoginForm.java

```
package com.mundodescuento.model.request_params;

/**
 * Created by gmuniz on 2/4/15.
 */
public class LoginForm {

    private final String email;
    private final String password;

    private LoginForm(final Builder builder) {
        this.email = builder.email;
        this.password = builder.password;
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private String email;
        private String password;

        public Builder email(final String email) {
            this.email = email;

            return this;
        }

        public Builder password(final String password) {
            this.password = password;

            return this;
        }

        public LoginForm build() {
            return new LoginForm(this);
        }
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

}
```

I've lost every clue about this, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try changing `minifyEnabled false` to `runProguard false` and re-run gradle

Comment: Error:(54, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'
The project 'MundoDescuento' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.

Comment: right you need to update gradle distribution for this to work...

Comment: okay, yeah your right this is not the problem. see answer below

Comment: Can you Post the full MundoDescuentoApplication.java  code it would be a big help

Comment: @inner_class7 I've added the classes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ... Finally I came up with the solution.

I can't explain it in detail, it seems there was an issue dealing with annotations and google-guice dependency internally.

My application was fully runnable across whole Android API levels after I moved version to:

```
compile 'com.google.inject:guice:4.0-beta5:no_aop'
```

It didn't has any relation to multidex configuration.

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was solved by changing and adding few things. 
First of all needed to be enable multidex by adding

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

then adding this dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.inject:guice:4.0-beta5:no_aop'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'  
}
```

changing in manifest's application

```
<application
    ...
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    ...
</application>
```

*** or if you have your own application class then android:name=".yourApllication" that must extend MultiDexApplication

For more info
https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have the following settings:

[image: Setup Multi Dex with resources in Android Studio]

**Update**

It looks like the real problem is the initialization of the LoginForm throwing a 
`java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` which is causing a null pointer on LoginForm which is occurring at line 22 `MundoDescuentoApplication.java:22`

Please, can you post this code for this class?

Comment: I've already have declared.. `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'` I double checked anyways I was missing `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'` ... something else I've tried inspired in your answer was changing version of `compile 'com.google.inject:guice:3.0:no_aop'` to `compile 'com.google.inject:guice:3.0'` with no luck, but when I got back to no_aop version, the stacktrace was the same, but with another file, also under the same package.

Comment: As I said, I declared `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'` but when I execute `./gradlew :app:androidDependencies` that dependency is not listed... Any clue with this?

Comment: I will take a look for you and update a bit later. It seems this isn't the answer...